# Using R list for lookup

Tags: r

I'm working with a large set of survey responses and trying to do a lookup (to get question titles into my dataframe) using values stored in a list. I fear I'm overlooking something simple with my indexing but I just can't make it happen. Here is a reproducible example:

```
survey.data <- data.frame(
  question.number = c("q2","q3","q4","q5")
)

titles <- list(q1="question1", 
           q2="question2", 
           q3="question3", 
           q4="question4", 
           q5="question5")
```

After a bit of data manipulation that involves removing some questions, I try to create a new question.title variable in my data frame using the following bit of list indexing to pull in the correct titles:

```
survey.data$question.title <- titles[survey.data$question.number]
```

which gives the output:

```
    question.number question.title
1   q2  question1
2   q3  question2
3   q4  question3
4   q5  question4
```

You can see that the new variable is not applying a lookup, just 'importing' all values of the list beginning at the first one.

I can't find any applicable help on doing this kind of lookup with a list, so perhaps it just isn't advisable? I'd be very grateful for a fix or an alternative.

Comment: +1 for sharing a reproducible example along with what you've tried and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution, but before sharing it, I've modified your data a little bit by adding a repeated question ("q2"):

```
survey.data <- data.frame(
  question.number = c("q2","q3","q4","q5", "q2")
)

titles <- list(q1="question1", 
               q2="question2", 
               q3="question3", 
               q4="question4", 
               q5="question5")
```

The solution uses `match` and `unlist`.

```
survey.data$question.title <- unlist(titles[match(survey.data$question.number, 
                                                  names(titles))])
survey.data
#   question.number question.title
# 1              q2      question2
# 2              q3      question3
# 3              q4      question4
# 4              q5      question5
# 5              q2      question2
```

How does this differ from the two solutions already present at the time of writing this?

Two main ways:

1. Neither of those solutions will accommodate the duplicated "q2" question.

   ```
   > survey.data$question.title <- titles[names(titles) %in% survey.data$question.number]
   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "question.title", value = list(q2 = "question2",  : 
     replacement has 4 rows, data has 5
   > survey.data$question.title <- titles[levels(survey.data$question.number)]
   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "question.title", value = list(q2 = "question2",  : 
     replacement has 4 rows, data has 5
   ```
2. Both of the other solutions retain a `list` structure for the "question.title" column (as this solution would also do, if it were not for the use of `unlist`) which will be problematic if you are trying to do things like export the data to a csv file later on. It's particularly troublesome because there is no visual indication that the resulting column is a `list`, but you can verify that by viewing the `str`ucture of the resulting `data.frame`.

Comment: Excellent Ananda, thank you. The 'unlist' aspect of your answer is particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
survey.data$question.title <- titles[names(titles) %in% survey.data$question.number]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the levels in the list, like this:

```
> survey.data$question.title <- titles[levels(survey.data$question.number)]
> survey.data
  question.number question.title
1              q2      question2
2              q3      question3
3              q4      question4
4              q5      question5
```

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the speedy response. This certainly looks right in the output but I see that the new `question.title` variable is a list rather than a character vector - is this what I'll get if I want to lookup from a list? I'd like to be able to convert it to a factor or at least character vector. But happy to accept your response if this is as far as I can get.

Comment: Thanks again Simon, but Ananda's answer covered this so I've accepted.